# What determines the sign of a separation constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am studying the method of separation of variables for the heat equation.  I am struggling to understand why the separation constant takes on a positive or negative value.  For instance if we apply the method of separation of variables to this equation.
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \frac{k}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} )
$$

looking for product solutions $u(r,t)=\phi(r)h(t)$ then dividing by $\phi h $ yields...
$$\frac{1}{kh}\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{r \phi} \frac{d}{dr} (r \frac{d \phi}{dr})=-\lambda$$

But the following problem ends up with a positive separation constant.
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= k \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}
$$

looking for product solutions $u(x,t)=\phi(x)h(t)$ then dividing by $k \phi h $ yields...
$$\frac{1}{kh}\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{\phi} \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}=\lambda$$

Why does the first problem end up with a negative constant and the second gets  a positive one?

Edit: Does it have something to do with this question [Why can we assume the separation constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759999/why-can-we-assume-the-separation-constant)?

Comment: You can put $-\lambda$ or $\lambda$. There's not problem.

Comment: If the time interval is $[0,+\infty),$ I think in both cases we should have a negative constant, otherwise $h(t)=e^{k\lambda t}$ diverges in time

Comment: It's not over [0,+infinity], we are evaluating at equilibrium over x from 0 to L. So either time =0 or dt=0  This is a boundary value problem, it's leading up to calculating initial conditions (where t=0) and/or equilibrium, where u(x,0) = f(x) and dt=0, so we can effectively describe u(x,t) as u(x).  I'm not sure if that makes any sense.  This problem is from Richard Haberman 4th eddition Applied Partial Differential Equations.